# How to build a generic Type from Type?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, types

Is there any way to build a generic type like this?

```
Type underlyingType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
Type genericType = typeof(Action<underlyingType>);
```

I know it may not be possible. so to get workarounds : I want to create a delegate `Action<T>` for setter of some properties.

```
var type = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
var defaultVal = type.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(type) : null;

var setter = (Action<object>)propertyInfo
    .GetSetMethod(true)
    .CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<object>), this);

var resetter = new Action(() => setter(defaultVal));
return resetter;
```

This does not work. because I have to pass exact matching type. If Property setter takes double I have to pass `Action<double>` then it works.

I have Generic container type and Underlying Type in hand. how can I mix them?

---

Note that I'm working on **group** of properties taken from a class. **not** a single property.

```
var props = GetType().GetProperties(Flags);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Type.MakeGenericType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype(v=vs.140).aspx):

```
Type underlyingType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
Type genericType = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(underlyingType);
```

You can then create the delegate (assuming you have a `MethodInfo` named `targetMethodInfo`):

```
Delegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(genericType, targetMethodInfo);
```

Comment: Very nice and clean approach. i will mark this as answer because it answers the question it self. (now i have another question in mind is `DynamicInvoke` better or `SetValue` or are there any better ways.)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this, How ever I'm calling `DynamicInvoke` and it seems to be slow any way.

```
var ptype = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
var defaultVal = ptype.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(ptype) : null;
var type = Type.GetType($"System.Action`1[{ptype}]");
var setter = prop.GetSetMethod(true).CreateDelegate(type, this);
var resetter = new Action(() => setter.DynamicInvoke(defaultVal));
return resetter;
```

So maybe this approach is better.

```
var ptype = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
var defaultVal = ptype.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(ptype) : null;
var resetter = new Action(() => propertyInfo.SetValue(this, defaultVal));
```